# Silverlight problem on windows server 2003

Tags: silverlight, windows-server-2003

I have installed silverlight 2 on windows server 2003. but when I browse silverlight sites, nothing is shown. Please help me?

Comment: What browser are you using IE7/Firefox3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a firewall software causes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed the [Silverlight plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/resources/install.aspx) in your browser. It doesn't have anything to do with Windows Server 2003 OS, as it is a cross-platform, cross-browser .NET plugin.

If you are using the IE7 browser and having problems then you may want to check out this thread on the Silverlight forums "[Silverlight will not work with IE 7](https://silverlight.net/forums/p/66153/162070.aspx)"

Answer (score 0):

On windows 2003 the first thing I look at when there is a problem like that is to look at the browser permissions relating to the site.  It could be that your IE settings won't allow it to use the silverlight control.